# Problem occured in IE8 Compatibility view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, compatibility-mode

I am using the Jquery and asp.net pages in my web application. In IE8 compatibility some of control width not getting render properly : dialog open with some auto width but the dialog title width not getting properly width as its content gets. Also some of the drop down list shown with very less width size.

How to solve the problem .....

Thanks..

Comment: don't test with compatibility view, its not representative for the actual browser. Test it in the actual browser and then i would post some code and maybe a screenshot. No-one can help you with the vague information you gave.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple: Don't use compatibility mode.

You can prevent IE from using compatibility mode by specifying th`X-UA-Compatible` meta tag, as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

Put that in your header and IE will stop using compatibility mode (unless the user sets it manually, of course; can't do much about that!)

It is important to note that compatibility mode is not actually 100% the same as a real copy of IE7. It has a number of bugs and quirks that do not appear in the real thing. You didn't specify whether your problems are occurring in a real IE7 or not, but if you need your site to support IE7, you should test with a real copy of IE7, not IE8's compatibility mode. (You can install all versions of IE together using a tool like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), which is great for cross-version testing)

Also, just in case you're confusing 'compatibility mode' with 'quirks mode', I should mention that you should make sure you have a valid doctype at the top of your page. This should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope that helps.